# Fast way to expand a column of lists in pandas data frame to a single column

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with text and sentiment score corresponding to it. I've created a column which stores all the bigrams in a column. Now I want to create a Dataframe which has this bigram column expanded with the score against it, when I do the second step using a for loop it's painfully slow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svn0u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NieOe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pandas >= 0.25**
You can use `explode`.

```
df = df.explode('bigrams')
```

**Dummy Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'score':[0.2,0.3],
               'bigrams':[['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'],['f','g']]})

print(df1)
```

=========================

**df1:**

```
    score   bigrams
0   0.2     [a, b, c, e]
1   0.3     [f, g]
```

===========================

```
df1 = df1.explode('bigrams')
print(df1)
```

=============================

**df1:**

```
    score   bigrams
0   0.2     a
0   0.2     b
0   0.2     c
0   0.2     e
1   0.3     f
1   0.3     g
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: update your pandas version. Do `pip install -U pandas`